# Acumatica Inventory Summary Inquiry all items via REST APi

Tags: acumatica

I need to retrieve the inventory summary for all Stock Items so that I can update an external site's inventory according to the "Available For Shipment" field on the inventory summary.  I have attempted running the inventory summary via the rest API using the following method after logging in:

```
URL: https://mycompany.acumatica.com/entity/Default/6.00.001/InventorySummaryInquiry

Method: PUT

Request Body:
{
    "InventoryID": "CW-500-MC-30"
}
```

However I receive this response:

```
{
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "modelState": {
        "": [
            "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path 'InventoryID', line 2, position 30."
        ]
    }
}
```

If there is a way to run the inquiry and have it return ALL stock items in an array, that would be ideal.

If that's not possible, what do I need to change to get the individual stock item inventory summary to work?

**UPDATE**:
After modifying my request body as @samol518 suggested, the request worked, but returned a very limited set of data (below).  I'm looking to get to the "quantity available for shipment".  Do I need to provide additional parameters to get more data returned?

```
{
    "id": "bf8e0bbc-63dc-4491-802d-090367af203a",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": null,
    "ExpandByLotSerialNumber": {},
    "InventoryID": {
        "value": "CW-500-MC-30"
    },
    "LocationID": {},
    "WarehouseID": {},
    "custom": {},
    "files": []
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to respond to your update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken the correct structure for the Request Body should resemble the following :

```
Request Body :
{
    "InventoryID": {"value": "CW-500-MC-30"}
}
```

Though if you want to retrieve all Stock Item, you could try and customize the inquiry in order to do so.

**Update:**

in order to retrieve all record, you might notice that the result fields are in a sub entity in the endpoint definition on the Web Service Endpoint screen (SM207060).

in order to return the data for these detail type sub entities, you must add the expand key word to your URL in the following format.
$expand=results

So your final URL should look like :

```
https://mycompany.acumatica.com/entity/Default/6.00.001/InventorySummaryInquiry?$expand=Results
```

Comment: This did fix the request, however I'm not getting all of the data from the screen when I run it through Acumatica's interface.  See updated question above.

Comment: Great, using $expand=Results worked perfectly.  I'll update my question if I figure out how to customize the report to work for all stock items.